# ¿Cómo hago para que cierto input aparezca según condicion previa en un formulario?

Tags: php, formularios

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
            <form id='formulario' action='#' method='post'>
            <h6>Selecciona el tipo de registro:</h6><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="horario" name="reg" value="horario" required>
                <label id="horario">Por horas</label>
                <input type="radio" id="diario" name="reg" value="diario" required>
                <label id="diario">Promedio Diario</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <h6>Selecciona el rango de fechas y horarios:</h6><br>
            Desde:
            <input type="date" name="from" value="<?php echo date("d-m-y"); ?>"><br><br>
            <select class="form-control" id="hora_desde" name="hora_desde">
                <option>00</option>
                <option>01</option>
            </select><br><br>
            Hasta:
            <input type="date" name="to" value="<?php echo date("d-m-y"); ?>"><br><br>
            <select class="form-control" id="hora_hasta" name="hora_hasta">
                <option>00</option>
                <option>01</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type='button' id='calcular' value='Generar gráfico' class="btn btn-primary mb-2" />
        </form>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que la parte de *"Seleccionar el rango de fechas y horarios"* solo aparezca si es que el usuario seleccionó el `checkbox` *"Por horas"* anterior.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad esto los puedes hacer con JAVASCRIPT y mucho más fácil, te dejo la explicación.
Lo primero que hice fue seleccionar los inputs tipo radio con `document.querySelectorAll('input[name="reg"]');` el cuál te va a regresar un array de las etiquetas que encuentre con ese atributo, en este caso tus dos inputs tipo radio, después los recorro con un `foreach`, después por medio de `document.getElementById()` selecciono esos inputs y le agrego un evento en este caso el `click` y al seleccionar uno u otro valida si el valor es igual al de **horario** o **diario**, si es **horario**, muestra el div, si no, lo oculta, para esto tuve que agregar un div con el id **mostrar** y con `style="display: none"` para poder ocultar desde un inicio, espero te funcione, cualquier duda hazla saber :)

```js
   
var div_oculto = document.getElementById('mostrar');

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="reg"]');

inputs.forEach(function(input){

document.getElementById(input.id).addEventListener('click',function(){

if(this.value === 'horario'){
  
  console.log(this.value)
  
  div_oculto.style.display = 'block';

}else{

div_oculto.style.display = 'none';
}

});

});
```

```html
   <form id='formulario' action='#' method='post'>
            <h6>Selecciona el tipo de registro:</h6><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="horario" name="reg" value="horario" required>
                <label id="horario">Por horas</label>
                <input type="radio" id="diario" name="reg" value="diario" required>
                <label id="diario">Promedio Diario</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="mostrar" style="display: none">
            <h6>Selecciona el rango de fechas y horarios:</h6><br>
            Desde:
            <input type="date" name="from" value="<?php echo date("d-m-y"); ?>"><br><br>
            <select class="form-control" id="hora_desde" name="hora_desde">
                <option>00</option>
                <option>01</option>
            </select><br><br>
            Hasta:
            <input type="date" name="to" value="<?php echo date("d-m-y"); ?>"><br><br>
            <select class="form-control" id="hora_hasta" name="hora_hasta">
                <option>00</option>
                <option>01</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <input type='button' id='calcular' value='Generar gráfico' class="btn btn-primary mb-2" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con jQuery puedes detectar si el radio button se ha pulsado y mostrar un DIV por ejemplo:

```
jQuery(function(){
                jQuery("input[name=horario]").change(function(){          
                    if ($(this).val() == "horario") {
                    jQuery("#DIVFec").slideDown()
                    }
                    else {
                    $('#DIVFechas').hide();
                    }                                                            
               });
        });


<form id='formulario' action='#' method='post'>
    <h6>Selecciona el tipo de registro:</h6><br>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="horario" name="reg" value="horario" required>
      <label id="horario">Por horas</label>
      <input type="radio" id="diario" name="reg" value="diario" required>
      <label id="diario">Promedio Diario</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="DIVFechas">
      <h6>Selecciona el rango de fechas y horarios:</h6><br>
      Desde:
      <input type="date" name="from" value="<?php echo date("d-m-y"); ?>"><br><br>
        <select class="form-control" id="hora_desde" name="hora_desde">
            <option>00</option>
            <option>01</option>
        </select><br><br>
       Hasta:
       <input type="date" name="to" value="<?php echo date("d-m-y"); ?>"><br><br>
       <select class="form-control" id="hora_hasta" name="hora_hasta">
            <option>00</option>
       </select>
       <br><br>
     </div>
     <input type='button' id='calcular' value='Generar gráfico' class="btn btn-primary mb-2" />
 </form>
```